# Create vector set

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I would want to create the vectors $(\pm x_1, \pm x_2, \ldots,\pm x_n), \; \{x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb R\}, \{n\in \mathbb N \}$.

For small $n$, this can be done manually (here $n=2, \, x_1 = 1, \, x_2 = 2$),

$(\pm 1, \pm 2) = \{(-1, -2), \;(1,-2),  \; (-1,2), \;(1,2) \}$

but the number of vectors increases exponentially. Is there a neat built-in syntax for this kind of list manipulation?

Comment: Perhaps `Tuples`?

Comment: `x={1,2,3,4}` and then `Tuples[{-#, #}&/@x]` or `Tuples[Transpose[{-x, x}]]`

Comment: You have repeated set {-1,-2}!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [Coolwater pointed out in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127348/create-vector-set#comment344486_127348) you could use the built-in `Tuples` command:

```
Tuples[{-#,#}&/@Range[1,n]]
```

which works pretty fast.

Another (slow) but natural approach is using `PatternMatching`:

```
n=2;
Flatten[Table[PlusMinus[i],{i,1,n}]//.{a___,PlusMinus[b_],c___}:>{{a,b,c},{a,-b,c}},n-1]
```

> {{1,2},{1,-2},{-1,2},{-1,-2}}

Comment: If one needs performance `Distribute[{-#, #} & /@ Range[1, 5], List]` is slightly faster than `Tuples[{-#, #} & /@ Range[1, 5]]` ;-)

Comment: Slot-free: `Tuples[Outer[Times, Range[n], {-1, 1}]]`.